# Why 2 boxes are overlapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, orgchart

Hi i'm having problem in `orgchart`, where boxes are overlapping.

i'm using this plugin: https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart

**Question:** why 2 `boxes` are overlapping without `margin`, how i can change the size of `boxes` dynamically.

**Problem is shown in below image:**  [image]

here is full **codepen** view: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/axJjwv

**NOTE: PLEASE SEE CODEPEN FOR FULL VIEW (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/axJjwv)**

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
         var ds = {
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'className': 'middle-level',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Li Jing', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'product-dept' },
            { 'name': 'Li Xin', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'product-dept',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'To To', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' },
                { 'name': 'Fei Fei', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' },
                { 'name': 'Xuan Xuan', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'className': 'middle-level',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'rd-dept' },
            { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'rd-dept',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'Ej 1', 'className': 'frontend1' },
                { 'name': 'Ej 2',  'className': 'frontend1' },
                { 'name':'Ej war', 'className': 'frontend1' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    var getId = function() {
      return (new Date().getTime()) * 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
    };


    var oc = $('#chart-container').orgchart({
       'data' : ds,
       'direction': 'l2r', 
       'width' : '200px',
       createNode : function($node,data){
            console.log('node ',$node,data);
       } 

      //  'nodeTitle' : 'false' 
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.orgchart{background: #333 !important;}

.orgchart { background: #fff; }
.orgchart td.left, .orgchart td.right, .orgchart td.top { border-color: #aaa; }
.orgchart .lines .downLine {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #ccc;
}
.orgchart .lines .leftLine {
     border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
.orgchart .lines .topLine {
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
.orgchart .lines .rightLine {
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}
.orgchart td>.down { background-color: #aaa; }
.orgchart .middle-level .title { background-color: #006699; }
.orgchart .middle-level .content { border-color: #006699; }
.orgchart .product-dept .title { background-color: #009933; }
.orgchart .product-dept .content { border-color: #009933; }
.orgchart .rd-dept .title { background-color: #993366; }
.orgchart .rd-dept .content { border-color: #993366; }
.orgchart .pipeline1 .title { background-color: #996633; }
.orgchart .pipeline1 .content { border-color: #996633; }
.orgchart .frontend1 .title { background-color: #cc0066; }
.orgchart .frontend1 .content { border-color: #cc0066; }
#chart-container {
    font-family: Arial;
    height: 420px;
    /* border: 2px dashed #aaa; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
} 

.orgchart.edit-state .edge { display: none; }
.orgchart .node .title {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.orgchart .node .title { height: 40px; line-height: 40px; }
.orgchart .node .title .symbol { margin-top: 1px; }

.orgchart .node .title {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.orgchart .node .title {
    height: 74px;
    line-height: 83px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="chart-container" style="text-align: right;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the details and diagrams and code... - but what is happening? Are you trying to show that there should be 3 boxes in that last column... but they are overlapping - so they look like just 1???

Comment: exactly what you said